# pd.to_datetime to replace DEC-11 or JUNE-11 values to date time column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have a column where Month and Year is given in the below format:

```
Dec-11', 'Nov-11', 'Oct-11', 'Sep-11', 'Aug-11', 'Jul-11',
       'Jun-11', 'May-11', 'Apr-11', 'Mar-11', 'Feb-11', 'Jan-11',
       'Dec-10', 'Nov-10', 'Oct-10', 'Sep-10', 'Aug-10', 'Jul-10',
       'Jun-10', 'May-10', 'Apr-10', 'Mar-10', 'Feb-10', 'Jan-10',
       'Dec-09', 'Nov-09', 'Oct-09', 'Sep-09', 'Aug-09', 'Jul-09',
       'Jun-09', 'May-09', 'Apr-09', 'Mar-09', 'Feb-09', 'Jan-09',
       'Dec-08', 'Nov-08', 'Oct-08', 'Sep-08', 'Aug-08', 'Jul-08',
       'Jun-08', 'May-08', 'Apr-08', 'Mar-08', 'Feb-08', 'Jan-08',
       'Dec-07', 'Nov-07', 'Oct-07', 'Sep-07', 'Aug-07', 'Jul-07', 'Jun-07'
```

I want to use the column for analysis and need capability to convert it to date time format so that i should able to filter on year or month depending on need.

I tried using - `pd.to_datetime(df['identity_d'])` but it gives error
then i tried using - `pd.to_datetime(df['identity_d'],errors='coerce')` - this does not give any error but converts all to NAT.
Finally i tried to use format with date time but no luck.

Can you please help me on how to covert?

Answer (score 4):

you are missing the format it argument :

I get the format [here](http://strftime.org/)

```
pd.to_datetime(df.identity_d.str.upper(), format='%b-%y', yearfirst=False)
```

here is the output :

```
0   2011-12-01
1   2011-11-01
2   2011-10-01
3   2011-09-01
4   2011-08-01
```